# Cannot get InputStream out of HttpEntity

Tags: java, android, httpentity

I have a HttpEntity I received from a web server. If I check that HttpEntity with getContentLength() it shows a value > 0. So there seems to be content. I run getContent() to get an InputStream and on that InputStream I run read() to get the content. On the first read() operation it throws an IO Exception that the stream is closed "Attempted read on closed stream.".

My Code is:

```
HttpEntity myEntity = myResponse.getEntity();
InputStream inputStream = myEntity.getContent();
inputStream.read();
```

So I am not calling close() on that stream. I cannot rule out that something is wrong with the HttpEntity, looking at myEntity in the debugger I see (no idea if that helps):

```
is1=EofSensorInputStream
eofWatcher=BasicManagedEntity
selfClosed=true
wrappedStream=null
```

getContentLength() on the InputStream shows the value as on the HttpEntity.

I have no clue where to start looking to figure out the issue. What can I check to find the issue?

Comment: Is it possible your server is sending the headers but not the body of the response?

Comment: maybe. But how can I find out? I don't have access to the server. Does the contentLength() include the header and the getContent() does not?

Comment: I'd think that content length is referring to the header, but it might not have received the whole body. Checking is a little harder. Try sending the same HTTP request through a TCP socket.

Comment: It may have been "already read" by spring

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to [this link](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent()) which says *REPEATABLE* entities can use `getContent()` and `writeTo(OutputStream)` procedures only once.

To know if your entity is *REPEATABLE*, use `isRepeatable()`.